# evaluating F" of function using fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

can someone help me differentiate this function and help me get F"(x)

$$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x^2}\ {(x^2-t)f(t)}\,dt$$

I cannot seem to get an answer despite applying the chain rule.

Comment: Try writing as $x^2\int_0^{x^2}f(t)dt-\int_0^{x^2}tf(t)dt$ and use the sum, product and chain rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint
$$F(x)=x^2\int_{0}^{x^2}f(t)dt-\int_{0}^{x^2}tf(t)dt
\Longrightarrow F'(x)=2x\int_{0}^{x^2}f(t)dt+2x^3f(x^2)-2x^3f(x^2)$$
so
$$F'(x)=2x\int_{0}^{x^2}f(t)dt$$
so
$$F''(x)=2\int_{0}^{x^2}f(t)dt+4x^2f(x^2)$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$F(x) = x^2 \int_0^{x^2} f(t) \, dt - \int_0^{x^2} tf(t) \, dt$$

Applying fundamental theorem of the calculus along with the chain rule,
$$F'(x) = 2x \int_0^{x^2} f(t) \, dt + x^2 \left(2xf(x^2)\right) - 2x(x^2 f(x^2)) = 2x \int_0^{x^2} f(t) \, dt$$

Applying once more,
$$F''(x) = 2\left(\int_0^{x^2} f(t) \, dt + x (2xf(x^2))\right) = 2\int_0^{x^2} f(t) \, dt + 4x^2 f(x^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Using Leibniz's rule
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \int\limits_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \!\! f(x, t) \, dt =
\int\limits_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \!\! \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x, t) \, dt +
f(x, b(x)) \, b'(x) - f(x, a(x)) \, a'(x)
$$
the first derivative is
\begin{align}
F'(x)
&= \int\limits_{0}^{x^2}\partial_x \left[ (x^2-t)\, f(t)\right]\,dt 
+ (x^2-x^2)\, f(x^2)\, (2x) \\
&= \int\limits_{0}^{x^2}2x \, f(t) \,dt 
\end{align}
The second derivative is
\begin{align}
F''(x)
&= \int\limits_{0}^{x^2}\partial_x \left[ 2x \, f(t)\right]\,dt 
+ 2x\, f(x^2) \, 2x \\
&= \int\limits_{0}^{x^2} 2f(t) \, dt 
+ 4x^2\, f(x^2) \\
\end{align}